# Retrieve the time a photo was taken

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation

I have an app that is supposed to take 3 pictures of a user within a time interval (say 200ms). The pictures are taken when the user taps a button.

Now to make sure the pictures are taken every 200 ms, I was thinking to access the time of when the photo was taken, but I am struggling with the documentation.

Here is what I am working with:

```
 func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {

    print("this is the call Back called when photo is done processing")
    if let error = error {
        print("error occured : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
    let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
    let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImage.Orientation.right)

    // do any of the above stuff contain time of when image was created? or can I derive it from any of them
}
```

Comment: Did you try `print(photo.metadata)` to see whether there's a capture date?

Comment: Thank you @matt! Yes I did, sorry, forgot to mention it. There are `DateTimeDigitized = "2019:03:12 09:37:00";` and `DateTimeOriginal = "2019:03:12 09:37:00";` but both of them have only seconds, not milliseconds, so it's hard for me to determine if the photos were created 200 ms apart

Comment: I end up taking pictures of a timer, so I can see the time on the picture. That will do for the moment

Answer (score 1):

Implement `photoOutput(_:didCapturePhotoFor:)` and examine `Date()`.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?)` delegate method

You have access to the `photo.timestamp` property.

It won't give you an absolute epoch time, but you can use the value to check if the interval of 200ms is respected between two consecutives captures.